# How to get result from string.format() with . and not with ,?

Tags: java, decimal

It returns me 1014,66  but i want it returning 1014.66   . Any suggestions?

```
           double money = 1000;
           double last = money * 1 * 1.04166;
           String gift = String.format("%1$,.2f",last);
```

Comment: Have you considered using `DecimalFormat` directly instead of `String.format`?

Comment: In this case the 1$ is a bit redundant as thee is only one argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the version of the `String.format` method that takes a `Locale`, and specify a locale that has a dot for decimal separator instead of a comma. For example, the US locale:

```
String gift = String.format(Locale.US, "%1$,.2f", last);
```

Comment: And change the pattern to `"%1$.2f"` if you want `1041.66` rather than `1,041.66`.

Comment: thnks! that's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 double money=1014.66;
 String str_money=String.valueOf(money);
 str.replace(',','.');
 return str;
```